# Netbeans: "main" class in java project

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans

I have a problem. I had project in eclipse. I changed my IDE to netbeans. 
Now i have problem, because in eclipse i had two source folder:

```
src/resources/main
src/java
```

All my jars i have in src/java, so i added src/java to my source in netbeans. 
But netbeans cant find class with "main" function in this project when this class is in src/java. Set main class in properties doesnt work.

But when i move it to src/resources/main it works fine.
Is it possible to have main class in src/java? Because i dont want change my structure

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/s2t3x.png]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two folders, and two issues.  We will fix them one at a time.  Then they will be explained.

1. make a main directory just under `src`
2. move the `src/java` folder into `src/main`, the result should be `src/main/java`

Then to fix your resources folder

1. move the `src/resources/main` into `src/main` renaming it at the same time to `src/main/resources`.

Now the rationale.  This isn't really about Eclipse or Netbeans, it is about Maven.  Maven imposes a particular directory naming convention.  Maven has put some time and effort into the convention, and it is generally well thought out.  More importantly, Maven has been pretty popular, and it's convention is seen as a de-facto standard.

Your Netbeans project isn't properly configured.  However, you could solve it one of two ways: you could configure every detail, or you could adapt to the standard expected conventions.  Since this isn't just Netbean's conventions, but also Maven's conventions, and most IDEs expect these conventions (or at least accommodate them), it is probably a better idea to follow them than to reconfigure you Netbeans to find sources and resources in nonstandard locations.

Comment: One of the best Java answers of the day. 1+

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Thank you for the kind compliment.

Answer (score 1):

You can manually specify the main entry class.

1. Right click on your Project in the project explorer
2. Click on properties
3. Click on Run
4. Make sure your Main Class is the one you want to be the entry point. (Make sure to use the fully qualified name i.e. mypackage.MyClass)
5. Click OK.
6. Run Project :)